# How to collect values with the same keys in a list from the two dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to interrsect two dictionaries with some common keys.
if the key from the two dictionaries is the same, the final dictionary should contain a **list** of the values from both dictionaries.

```
D1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}
D2 = {'A':10,'B':20,'X':3}
```

intersecting these two should give:

```
{'A':[1,10], 'B':[2,20]}
```

The intersection part works fine with

```
def intersect(D1,D2):
    newD = {}
    keys_D1 = set(D1.keys())
    keys_D2 = set(D2.keys())
    intersection = keys_D1 & keys_D2
    for i in intersection:
        newD[i] = D1.get(i)
    //...(looking for a way to append the values from D1 & D2 not just D1)
    return newD

newD = {'A':1,'B':2}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by list comprehension like;

```
>>> D1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}
>>> D2 = {'A':10,'B':20,'X':3}
>>> {a:[b, c] for a, b in D1.items() for a1, c in D2.items() if a == a1}
{'B': [2, 20], 'A': [1, 10]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
D1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}
D2 = {'A':10,'B':20,'X':3}
newD = {}
for key in D1.keys():
    try:
        if(D2[key]):
            newD[key] = [D1[key],D2[key]]
    except KeyError:
        continue
print newD
```

Regards

Comment: You could use just `if key in D1:` and also `if key in D2` instead of the try/except.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. After:

```
intersection = keys_D1 & keys_D2
```

You just need a dictionary comprehension:

```
{key: [D1[key], D2[key]] for key in intersection}
```

If you wanted to do it with your loop:

```
for i in intersection:
    newD[i] = [D1.get(i), D2.get(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
D1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}
D2 = {'A':10,'B':20,'X':3}

a_dict = {}

for key in D1:
    if key in D2:
        a_dict[key] = [D1[key], D2[key]]

a_dict
```

Comment: If you are iterating keys from D1 you don't need to check again whether they are in D1.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
D1 = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}
D2 = {'A':10,'B':20,'X':3}
D3 = {i:[] for i in list(set(D1.keys()) & set(D2.keys()))}
for i in D3:
    for j in [D1,D2]:
        D3[i].append(j[i])
```